# Clarifications on javamail properties

Tags: spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email from a spring boot application. I have it working but quite confused about a few properties. But it doesn't work unless set a from message to MimeMessageHelper explicitly.

```
helper.setFrom(configurationProperties.getEmailAlertSender());
```

What's the difference between the address set above and mail.host.username?

I am able to make it work only if both the mail.host.username and "from" address is the same.  What's the relation between these two?

```
@Autowired
ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender sender;

public void sendEmailAlertWithHTMLBody(AlertMessageDTO alertDTO) {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = sender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "utf-8");
    String htmlMsg = createEmailBody(alertDTO);
    try {
        helper.setText(htmlMsg, true);
        String rec = configurationProperties.getEmailAlertRecievers();
        helper.setTo(InternetAddress.parse(rec));
        helper.setSubject(alertDTO.getAlert());
        helper.setFrom(configurationProperties.getEmailAlertSender());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Properties

```
spring.mail.host: smtp.office365.com

spring.mail.host: 587

spring.mail.username: ext_sputhukkot@xyz.com 

spring.mail.password: asbcdef

alert.recievers: ext_qjsk@xyz.cl

alert.sender: ext_sputhukkot@falabella.cl
```

Answer (score 0):

from is youremail@gmail.com,
the username is your email or full mail address,
but from can't be name. it should be a mail address

Comment: Why they have to be same? If i am already providing a username to login to the mail server why do i have to set a from adress again?

Comment: form java mail specification (https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)  form address and username should be provided seperately
username for the authentication purpose. form address is used to set your address as sender.

Comment: @ShamilPuthukkot is this clarify your doubt ?

Comment: Not all mail server use your email address as your username.  And some mail servers will allow you to send from a different email address than you use when you authenticate.